# Particular column not saving in Production only? Heroku/RoR/PostgreSQL

Tags: heroku

i can't for the life of me figure out why one particular column in my User table is not being updated--but only in Production on Heroku (Ruby on Rails, PosgreSQL).

I have a user avatar_url string field which I update using a simple form. The form posts to the normal User controller update method. Works perfectly in development, test AND staging (on Heroku, staging in production mode) environments.

I've gone through Heroku logs on prod server--verified that the params hash is correct and has a value for {:user => { :avatar_url => "http://sometwitteravatar.com/somepic.jpg"}} and that this is posting to the user update action. But i only see one Update query and the only thing that gets updated is user.updated_at. i see no errors. I've also run rails console in production and verified that user.updated_at gets updated but not user.avatar_url

But all works perfect in identical staging environ on heroku run in production mode. what gives??

Comment: i should add that I am able to update the same user model elsewhere in production. i can update user.name, etc. but for some reason this particular form isn't working, just in production. the url isn't entered by the user, it's done programmatically.

Comment: omg this was so stupid, i wasn't doing anything wrong, something weird on Heroku was going on--all I needed to do was "heroku restart --r production"; restarted the dyno and it worked correctly! I'm fine deleting this question if need be